# Copy all data from one table to another via trigger | phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql

I'm pretty new to this whole trigger thing with PHPMyAdmin. I don't really know what I am doing wrong but I want simply to copy all the data from `table1` to `table2` like an archive or something like that. Everytime there is an insert it should copy the data to `table2`.

`Table1` has these attributes/fields:

```
ID
customerID
BookSN(SN = serialnumber)
created_at(when he lend the book)
updated_at(when he gave the book back)
```

`Table2`:

Has the same attributes/fields as `Table1`

I'm trying to solve this:

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER `simple_copy` AFTER INSERT ON table1
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
insert into table2(id, customerID, BookSN, created_at,updated_at)
select ?? -- i dont know what to write here...
from table1;
END;
//
delimiter ;
```

I would be really grateful if you can help me to fix this total mess.

Comment: 'Within the trigger body, the OLD and NEW keywords enable you to access columns in the rows affected by a trigger' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html - ie use a values clause rather than select and NEW.id etc as the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are some data in `table1` that you would want to copy in `table2` then first run this:

```
INSERT INTO table2(id, customerID, BookSN, created_at, updated_at)
SELECT id, customerID, BookSN, created_at, updated_at
FROM table1;
```

Then you can now use a trigger to continuously copy the newly inserted data from `table1` into `table2`.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `simple_copy` AFTER INSERT ON table1
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT INTO table2(id, customerID, BookSN, created_at, updated_at)
VALUE (new.id, new.customerID, new.BookSN, new.created_at, new.updated_at);
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

But if `table1` is empty then just go at once with the trigger.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy all columns you have to use like this

```
delimiter #
CREATE TRIGGER `simple_copy` AFTER INSERT ON table1
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
insert into table2(id, customerID, BookSN, created_at,updated_at)
values (new.id, new.customerID, new.BookSN, new.created_at,new.updated_at)
from table1;
END#
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Looks good but i get an error message directly in row 1 is there something wrong with the delimiter?

Comment: @DarkShadow Updated answer, which error you are getting may be because I added a semicolon.